# Decimal numbers sent over Serial get split and sent over multiple ticks

Tags: arduino-uno, node.js

Here is my Arduino sketch:

```
#include <HX711.h>
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
HX711 hx(9, 10, 128, 0.002229);
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,16,2);

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  hx.set_offset(-9635);
  lcd.init();                      // initialize the lcd 
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.begin(16,2);

}
void loop() {
  if(digitalRead(0) == LOW){
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(2,0);
    lcd.print("tare recieved");
    hx.tare();
  }

  double sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    sum += hx.bias_read();
    if(sum < 0) {
      sum = 0.00;
    }

  }
  sum = sum/10;
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(4,0);
  lcd.print("Weight");
  lcd.setCursor(5, 1);
  lcd.print(sum);
  lcd.print("g");
  Serial.println(sum);
  delay(10);
 }
```

Here is an example output as seen on the Arduino Serial Monitor:

```
150.34
150.39
150.40
150.37
150.38
```

The Problem is when the data reaches node-serialport the value is split up on multiple lines.

```
 comport.on("data", function (data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
 }
```

When i log the data... it comes back like this:

```
1
50.4
5
150.
49
15
0.47
150.
48
15
0.45
```

Is there anyway to have Arduino only send the data if it is the full value and not the split up values?

Comment: There is no such thing as "the full value". Serial works in characters. That's what serial means. It's up to you at the receiving end to combine the individual characters up into full strings.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in Majenko’s comment, the serial link is not packetized: it
transmits individual bytes and nothing else. If you need to convey a
notion of “data packet”, or “full message”, you will have to devise a
way to signal the message boundaries. This is called message “framing”.

Your Arduino is sending ASCII data. In this case, the most common way to
frame messages is linewise: each message is a single line, and each line
is terminated by an “end of line” sequence. The standard end of line
sequences are CR (carriage return, i.e. `0x0d` or `'\r'`), LF (line
feed, i.e. `0x0a` or `'\n'`), and the pair CRLF (CR followed by LF, or
`"\r\n"`).

Actually you are already doing that: you are using `Serial.println()`,
and this method automatically appends CRLF at the end of whatever it
prints. So now you just have to *parse* that at the other end: you put
all the incoming characters into a buffer until you see that incoming
CRLF. Then you know you have a full line, which you can report as an
entire message.

This procedure is very common and there is a standard Node.js module for
it. It once was part of the serialport module, but it seems to have
split into a separate module. It is called *parser-readline*, and you
would use it like this:

```js
const Readline = require("parser-readline"),
      parser = comport.pipe(new Readline({ delimiter: "\r\n" }));

parser.on("data", data => console.log(data.toString()));
```

C.f. the [documentation of
ReadLineParser](https://node-serialport.github.io/parsers/ReadLineParser.html).